# pass props to page using next page and next router?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am pushing a screen based on some data:

```
 if (waitData) {
    //@ts-ignore
    if (waitData?.events[0].args.message == "Loss") {
      router.push("/losescreen");
    }
    //@ts-ignore
    if (waitData?.events[0].args.message == "Win") {
      router.push("/winscreen");
    }
  }
```

This works fine, now I want to pass a prop to LoseScreen. This is LoseScreen:

```
const Loss: NextPage = () => {

return (...)

}

export default Loss
```

How can i do so? I am using React, Typescript, Next.js, and Next Router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use query string to pass something in the URL. And then access it in your Loss component:

```js
 if (waitData) {
    //@ts-ignore
    if (waitData?.events[0].args.message == "Loss") {
      router.push({pathname: "/losescreen", query: {somekey: "someValue" });
    }
  }
```

Then in your Loss component:

```js
const Loss: NextPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { somekey } = router.query

  console.log(somekey) // "someValue"

  return (...)

  }

export default Loss
```